# Why does this R ggplot code display aggregate values for each year?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing a peer-review and trying to understand this code. The resulting graph seems correct, but I can't figure out how it was able to be correct.

In the below example, tableA has more than 28k observations. I would assume it would need to be aggregated first before the aggregate can be graphed. So, what I would expect would be a data frame with 4 rows for each of the 4 years, not 28k rows.

Here are the columns of tableA, if that is helpful:

```
> names(tableA)
[1] "fips"      "SCC"       "Pollutant" "Emissions" "type"      "year"
```

And here is the code:

```
plot4 <- ggplot(tableA, aes(factor(year), Emissions/1000))+ geom_bar( stat = "identity")
print(plot4)
```

Comment: I can't imagine what the result looks like. Can you please simulate some data that mimics this behavior?

Comment: I agree with @RomanLuštrik - posting a question with no data and no example of what the output looks like basically shows a lack of effort on your part. Please do not do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a bar plot using ggplot, the default `position="stacked"`, meaning that if there is more than one value of `y` for each `x`, the resultant bars are stacked on top of each other. Since you have no grouping aesthetic to distinguish the bars, they are all the same fill color and the total height will be the sum of `y` for that `x`.

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(year=rep(2011:2014,each=5),emissions=1:20)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(year),y=emissions)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

This behavior is more of an artifact than a feature, though. AFAIK the idiomatic way to summarize data having multiple y-values for a given x-value is using `stat_summary(...)`, as in:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(year),y=emissions)) + stat_summary(fun.y=sum,geom="bar")
```

This produces a plot identical to the one above.